# Cosmic string gravity assist?

Tags: cosmic-string

Could a spacecraft hypothetically use the gravity of a cosmic string to carry itself along the length of the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the gravity assists are possible when orbiting objects that (a) have a gravitational field that (b) are moving, and since cosmic strings have gravitational fields and move, I think you can theoretically perform this maneuver to gain momentum in a direction perpendicular to the string. How much you get out of it will depend on the string tension, how close you get / how fast you are moving, and how fast the string is moving. However, since the potential is essentially constant along the length of the string, I don't think a gravity assist would help you traverse the length of the string.